# How to run tasks in Parallel?

Tags: vb.net

I have the following code which consists of two methods that I want to run in parallel : LoopA and LoopB

```
Sub Main(args As String())
    Proceed()
End Sub

Public Async Function Proceed() As Task
    Task.WaitAll(LoopA, LoopB)
End Function

Private Function LoopA() As Task
    While True
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        Console.WriteLine("A")
    End While
End Function

Private Function LoopB() As Task
    While True
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        Console.WriteLine("B")
    End While
End Function
```

When running this code, the two tasks don't run in parallel. I'm getting only A, A, A...

[image]

Can anyone tell me why these tasks aren't running in parallel ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your methods aren't asynchronous.

```vb
Sub Main(args As String())
    Proceed()
End Sub

Public Function Proceed() As Task
    Task.WaitAll(LoopA, LoopB)
End Function

Private Async Function LoopA() As Task
    Await Task.Run(Async Function()
                       While True
                           Await Task.Delay(1000)
                           Console.WriteLine("A")
                       End While
                   End Function)
End Function

Private Async Function LoopB() As Task
    Await Task.Run(Async Function()
                       While True
                           Await Task.Delay(1000)
                           Console.WriteLine("B")
                       End While
                   End Function)
End Function
```

If you're not going to actually write those methods so that they are asynchronous then they should each be a `Sub` rather than a function and you can add the asynchronicity when you call them:

```vb
Sub Main(args As String())
    Proceed()
End Sub

Public Function Proceed() As Task
    Dim taskA = Task.Run(AddressOf LoopA)
    Dim taskB = Task.Run(AddressOf LoopB)

    Task.WaitAll(taskA, taskB)
End Function

Private Sub LoopA()
    While True
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        Console.WriteLine("A")
    End While
End Sub

Private Sub LoopB()
    While True
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        Console.WriteLine("B")
    End While
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`Async` and `Await` do not automatically put things into different threads.  In and of themselves, the only functionality they have is to set things up so that *if* there is some kind of processing that can be done behind the scenes, *then* control will return to the UI until the processing concludes.

One common use case for `Async` and `Await` doesn't even involve threading, per se.  It involves IO, which will run entirely on the main thread (see Stephen Cleary's "There Is No Thread" blog article).

`Async` and `Await` are useful *helpers* for making interaction with parallelism better and more natural, but you will have to introduce the parallelism yourself.  For CPU-bound processing which is already being done in the context of `Task`s, the best way to do this is using `Task.Run`, which is covered in jmcilhinney's excellent answer.